# How to configure GithubAction to assume role to access my CodeBuild Project

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using GithHub Actions with CodeBuild,when I run GitHub Actions,I am getting error message CodeBuild project name can not be found.The issue is that my codebuild project is in my assumed role(sandbox_role) but github action is looking for the project in the root account that i configured as environment variable in github secret.How can I configure my GitHub Action workflows to first connect to the root then from there assume sandbox_role to get my codebuild project?below is my code sample..I am using terragrunt/terraform code to provision my environment

```
name:'GitHub Actions For CodeBuild'
on:
  pull_request:
      branches:
       - staging
jobs:
 CodeBuild:
    name:'Build'
    runs-on:ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      -name:'checkout'
       uses:actions/checkout@v2

     -name:configure AWS credentials
      uses:aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1
    -name:Run CodeBuild
     uses: aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1
     with:
       project-name: CodeBuild
       buildspec-override: staging/buildspec.yml
       env-vars-for-codebuild: |
        TF_INPUT,
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        AWS_REGION,

 env:
      TF_INPUT: false 
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure if this works, but whenever I use roles I also pass the role ARN "to tell" AWS which is the role you are using and which permissions it should have.
This role ARN can be added in the configuration and credentials file:

Configuration:

```
 region = us-east-1
 output = json
 role_arn = arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/role-name
 source_profile=default
```

Credentials:

```
 [default]
 aws_access_key_id="your_key_id"
 aws_secret_access_key="your_access_key"
 aws_session_token="your_session_token"
 source_profile=default
```